# Статический метод создания матрицы использующий внутренний конструктор

Tags: c++

Собственно нужно создать статический метод в классе `Matrix`, возвращающий мне матрицу (или указатель, не разобрался ещё), который будет использовать конструктор этого класса.

Метод:

```
static Matrix inicilaze()
{
    printf("Please enter dimensions of matrix\n");
    printf("Input m: ");
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << "\nInput n: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    Matrix mtrx(m, n);
    return mtrx;
}
```

Конструктор:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const int m, const int n)
{
    this->M = m;
    this->N = n;
    arr = new int*[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    arr[i] = new int[n];
    this->input();
}
```

Input-метод заполнения этого класса.

После создания и заполнения вывожу его на экран.

```
auto mtrx = Matrix::inicilaze();
mtrx.print();
```

Где я ошибся?

Comment: У вас нет конструктора копирования небось?

Comment: А без него можно обойтись? Хочу именно через статический метод её создавать.

Comment: Создать через статический метод — это можно. А как вы собираетесь вернуть объект из метода `inicilaze` без копирования? Стековую переменную вы не вернёте никак.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, `inicilaze` - это на каком языке?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, статический метод, конструирующий матрицу — не такая уж и плохая идея. Правда, матрицу не стоит возвращать по значению, т. к. вам придётся для этого уметь копировать её, а это неправильно: матрица может быть большой! Именованный конструктор (так обычно называется эта идиома) должен по идее возвращать указатель:

```
static Matrix* inicilaze()
{
    // ...
    return new Matrix(m, n);
}
```

---

Отмечу, правда, что ваш метод `inicilaze` не очень хорош. Он занимается вводом данных с клавиатуры, это не та часть логики, которая принадлежит самому классу `Matrix`. Я бы посоветовал вынести это в отдельную функцию:

```
Matrix* interactiveInputMatrix()
{
    cout << "Please enter dimensions of matrix" << endl;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое это возвращать указатель:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Matrix> initilaze()
{
    //...
    return {new Matrix{m, n}};
}
```

Для использования `unique_ptr` понадобится заголовок `memory`. С использованием этого умного указателя, Вам не придётся заботиться о выделенной памяти - она будет освобождена автоматически.

Вариант с возвращением объекта сложнее, но не сильно. Для этого нужно переопределить конструктор копирования(не обязательно):

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& rhs)
{
    M = rhs.M;
    N = rhs.N;
    arr = new int*[M];
    for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[N];
        memcpy(arr[i], rhs.arr[i], N*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

и перемещения:

```
Matrix::Matrix(Matrix&&)
{
    M = rhs.M;
    N = rhs.N;
    arr = rhs.arr;

    rhs.arr = nullptr;
}
```

Разумеется, нельзя забывать и о деструкторе:

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    if(arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            delete [] arr[i];
        delete[] arr;
    }
}
```

Я сделал предположение, что `arr` это переменная-член класса, которая хранит матрицу.

Добавив 3 вышеозначенные функции Ваша функция должна отработать нормально и оптимально. Разумеется там есть целый полигон для улучшений, как-то отказ от голых указателей и прочего, но это другая история.

P.S. правильно писать *ini**t**ialization*, а не *ini**c**ialization*

Comment: Если вы говорите о конструкторе копирования, наверное стоит упомянуть о [big three rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (и сделать деструктор виртуальным или запретить наследование).

Comment: @VladD, по уму тут можно было бы много чего сказать, но, на мой взгляд, это не имеет смысла. Я вообще использовал бы `vector` и убрал бы деструктор и всё остальное, да и ещё много чего изменил бы. Но вопрос не в этом и не вижу смысла предлагать очень широкий ответ, на вполне конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Может, и так. В любом случае, я упомянул об этом в комментарии, кто хочет — прочитает или переспросит. Mission complete.